# What is the practical difference between two-way binding and the twoWay binding behavior in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia it is possible to specify a two-way binding in two different ways.  One is by using an explicit binding and the other is by utilizing the twoWay binding behavior.

```
<input value.bind="firstName & twoWay"/>
// vs.
<input value.two-way="firstName"/>
```

Is there any practical difference between the two?  If so, when should I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical difference. However there are some situation where you cannot use "explicit" bindings. Those work for attribute bindings only. For example if you need to define a two-way binding on a div content, you will need to use a behavior:

```
<div>${firstName & twoWay}</div>
```

Comment: Another thing to mention is, that the attribute must always be written in dash-case to be valid html and the binding behaviour needs to be written in camel-case because it must be a valid javascript variable declaration.